# Why not remove one of these identical posts?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The content of these 2 questions are identical :

- [C, Linux: Receiving data from multiple multicast address on same port - how to distinguish them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741936/c-linux-receiving-data-from-multiple-multicast-address-on-same-port-how-to-d?lq=1)
- [Receving multiple multicast feeds on the same port - C, Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741611/receving-multiple-multicast-feeds-on-the-same-port-c-linux)

It is noted that the questions have been merged, but why not remove completely the one marked as [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741936/c-linux-receiving-data-from-multiple-multicast-address-on-same-port-how-to-d?lq=1) ?
As there is no more answers on it, it does not bring additional information.

Comment: Based on your comment, I think a clearer title might be, "Why does a question-merge not turn the merged question into a redirect?" or "Why are merged questions visible? Why not turn them into redirects?" Although maybe that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

It's there as a reference to the canonical question.  Users who find the duplicate question when searching, or who are pointed to that question via a URL that had previously been exposed externally, will be pointed to the canonical question instead of simply getting a 404 message.

Comment: An other way could be that both url reach the same [target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741611/receving-multiple-multicast-feeds-on-the-same-port-c-linux) ?

Comment: @mpromonet: Unless you are logged in, you will be automatically redirected.